# how to recall a timer after some delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to restart the timer after some delay. How do i make a callback? please help...

```js
var i = 0;
var createInterval = setInterval(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++i);

    //delay
    setTimeout(function() {
        return createInterval;
    }, 10000);

    if (i === 10) {
        clearInterval(createInterval);
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5qtfh2pL/)

Comment: if `createInterval` is a function, you'd need to call it, `createInterval()`

Comment: Where exactly do you think the return value from the timeout's callback is going? Also, `createInterval` is just an integer. Pull the timeout out from the interval callback, and create the interval within the timeout's callback function.

Comment: Now after you've edited the question, the answer is: you can't. Once an interval has been cleared, it is gone, you can't restart it. You've to create a new interval. Declare a function, and refer it as a callbak when creating intervals.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your precious time. Maybe i wasn't clear enough with my question.

```
<div id="counter"></div>

(function product_timer() {
  var product_interval = 20, //20 seconds
    delay = 10000; //10 seconds
  //product interval
  productInterval = setInterval(function() {
    product_interval--;
    $('#counter').html(product_interval+'s');
    if (product_interval === 0) {
      $('#counter').html('Please Wait...');
      clearInterval(productInterval);
      setTimeout(function() {
        //delay and callback product timer
        product_timer();
      }, delay); // 10 s
    }
  }, 1000);
}());
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/5qtfh2pL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var i = 0;

    function A() {
        $('#counter').html(++i);
    
        if (i === 10) {
            clearInterval(createInterval);
        }
        
        //delay
        setTimeout(function() {
            A();
        }, 10000);
    }
    var createInterval = setInterval(A, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

try this code

it creates a function A() which would be called at specific intervals, inside it is called recursively in a setTimeout();

Answer (score 0):

```js
var i = 0;
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000);
function myFunction() {
    $('#counter').html(++i);
    if (i < 10) {
        setTimeout(myFunction, 10000);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Use two `setTimeout`. call the same function after some time.

Answer (score 0):

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is an asynchronous function, it'll not block your code, but will execute the function after the delay you provided. [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) will execute your code every X milliseconds until you stop it using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). See my example below :

```js
var i = 0;

function increment () {
  $('#counter').html(++i);
  
  if (i === 10) {
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(increment, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="counter">0</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To start a timer after some delay first create a function to increment timer and then call it after X seconds and setInterval will be executed after every Y seconds and clearInterval to clear timer set by setInterval as demonstarted on https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

Check this code which demonstrates above statement -

```js
var i = 0;
var createInterval = function() {
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    $('#counter').html(++i);
    if (i === 10) {
      $('#text').html('Stop');
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}

$('#text').html('Waiting... for 5 sec to start timer');

setTimeout(function() {
  $('#text').html('Start...');
  createInterval();
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Hope, this works for you.. :) :)